# Change Input of given Function

Tags: graphics

I want to frite a function to intersect regions. All the regions are closed lines of different length. 
My code is:

```
Kiste = {Line[{{10, -20, 0}, {90, -20, 0}, {90, 20, 0}, {10, 20, 
  0}, {10, -20, 0}}]};

Kiste2 = {Line[{{10, -20, 0}, {70, -20, 0}, {70, 10, 0}, {10, 10, 
  0}, {10, -20, 0}}]};

RegionIntersection[Kiste2, Kiste]
```

Returning:

```
Line[{{{10,-20,0},{10,10,0}},{{10,-20,0},{70,-20,0}}}]
```

This I want to change to:

```
Line[{{10,-20,0},{10,10,0},{10,-20,0},{70,-20,0}}]
```

So I can reuse the intersected as a new Line, which is the input for many functions in a pretty extensive custom library I use.

Is there any way of changin the Line in that way?

Comment: But it is a valid syntax and what you want has one segment doubled ({10,10,0}  {10,-20,0}) which is not expected. Anyway: `Catenate /@ 
 Line[{{{10, -20, 0}, {10, 10, 0}}, {{10, -20, 0}, {70, -20, 0}}}]`

Comment: Not sure what it might be good for but you can obtain it with `Join @@@ Line[{{{10, -20, 0}, {10, 10, 0}}, {{10, -20, 0}, {70, -20, 
     0}}}]`

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher What I am trying to do is to write a function that is able to intersect such line-objects as Kiste and Kiste2. Since i am a Mathematica-novice, this is the first problem i ran into. 
Thanks for your solution though.